# Differential equation: $2x^2y'=y^2(2xy'-y)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Solve the differential equation: $$2x^2y'=y^2(2xy'-y)$$
I tried to convert it to the form of a total differential equation.
$$\begin{array}{lrl}
&2x^2y'&=y^2(2xy'-y)\\
\Leftrightarrow&y'(2x^2-2xy^2)+y^3&=0\\
\Leftrightarrow&y^3dx+(2x^2-2xy^2)dy&=0
\end{array}$$
Here, I tried my best to find the integrating factor, but can't. Of course, it has no form $\mu (x)$ or $\mu (y)$.

I also tried to set $\dfrac{y}{x}=u^\alpha$. I wanted a perfect "$\alpha$" in order to have a "beautiful" form. But, it isn't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2x^2y'=y^2(2xy'-y)$$
$$y'(2x^2-2xy^2)=-y^3$$
Consider now $x'$ instead of $y'$:
$$(2x^2-2xy^2)=-x'y^3$$
This is Bernoulli 's differential equation.

Comment: Oh, thank guy. Good solution.

Comment: You're welcome ...@MrCR